# Python groupby[A] and convert (dynamically) column B to several columns with count()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'A': {0: '1',  1: '7',  2: '7',  3: '1',  4: '7',  5: '1'},
 'B': {0: 'S', 1: 'S', 2: 'D', 3: 'D', 4: 'D', 5: 'S'}})
display(df1.head())
```

I want to convert above dataframe (dynamically) to this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'A': {0: '1',  1: '7'},
'S': {0: 2, 1: 1},
'D': {0: 1, 1: 2},
})
display(df2.head())
```

[image]
[image]

I know how to use 'groupBy', but I don't know how to automatically convert fields into new columns.

Comment: @jezrael This is not my problem. In my case, It may be 5 columns or more. I want this number of columns to be added automatically

Comment: OOps, you are right, need `pd.crosstab(df1.A, df1.B).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael Thank you but I don't understand your answer. I need something like this:  df.groupBy(['A'])['B'].countAndConvert(). Can you post complete answer to my question ?

Comment: use `df.groupBy(['A'])['B'].size(). unstack(fill_value=0)`